# Fetching data to make default values in c#?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

How could I get a default depending if the user is logged in or not?

```
public class ShippingDetails {

  public ShippingDetails() {                
    if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name != "") {
        Name = "";                
    }             
   }

   public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You mean get the users login name, otherwise just give them a dummy name? Check if they're logged in using `Request.IsAuthenticated`. If they are, grab the username, if not just set it.

```
if (HttpContext.Current.Request.IsAuthenticated)
    Name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
else
    Name = "User";
```

Comment: cool. seems like this works too. Wonder if there's a benefit in using your method over mine, or vice versa

Comment: @Shredder, Not sure, but I prefer to use Request.IsAuthenticated because it makes it clear what I'm checking.

Answer (score 0):

You can also check

```
if (HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.IsAuthenticated) {
   Name = HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name;
} 
else 
{ 
   Name = "Anonymous"
}
```